# Как убрать пустое пространство после последней строки в datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Только не предлагайте, пожалуйста, перекрасить `datagridview`. Спасибо.

В общем есть `datagridview`. У него выставленный мной размер и, соответственно, при отсутствии в нём записей - вместо записей пустое пространство:

[image: datagridview без записей]

При добавлении записей пустое пространство постепенно заполняется до появления полосы прокрутки:

[image: datagridview с записями без полосы прокрутки]

При появлении полосы прокрутки и последующей прокрутке до конца вниз, внизу остается серое пространство (не последняя строка, а пустое пространство):

[image: datagridview с полосой прокрутки]

Как от него избавиться?

P. S. Переопределение размера таблицы тоже не подходит, потому что высота строк варьируется.

Comment: datagridview выравнивает область прокрутки по верхней границе строчки, поэтому снизу оказывается пустое пространство. Не знаю как в WinForms, но в WPF есть настройка для этого

Comment: размеры нужно указывать относительно использованных шрифтов, а не от балды `x = 100; y= 129`

Comment: @DigitalCore размеры чего?

Comment: В WPF для решения этой проблемы необходимо установить `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"`, для WinForms я аналога не нашел.

Comment: Почему вообще полоса прокрутки прокручивается не до конца (до края последней строки), а ещё на какое-то пространство?

Comment: А уменьшить высоту блока datagridview не получится? Я имею ввиду, так чтобы высота была кратна высоте строки. Похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661303/how-to-fit-datagridview-width-and-height-to-its-content) в англоязычной ветке.

Comment: Выравнивание идет по верхней строке, а не по нижней.

Comment: @Rootware высота строк варьируется

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko если высота строки может быть определена, то ссылка которую я вам дал актуальна.

Answer (score 1):

Как верно заметили **Андрей NOP** и **@Alexander Petrov**, `DataGreedView` в WinForms выравнивает строки грида по верхнему краю. Изменить такое поведение для стандартного контрола не получится.

---

Если высота строк зависит от контента ячеек, дальше можно не читать, какой-то адекватный результат можно получить в единичных случаях. В общем виде задача не имеет решения для стандартного контрола. Лучше поискать стороннее решение для WinForms или использовать WPF.

---

Один из вариантов подогнать высоту самого `DataGreedView`, однако это не всегда возможно, например если размер жестко регламентирован дизайном формы или на контроле использовано свойство `Dock` для автоматической подгонки высоты контрола под высоту контейнера, в котором он размещен.

Также есть возможность подогнать высоту строк и заголовка, если он есть, таким образом, чтобы свести к минимуму размер пустого пространства ниже последней строки. Для этого понадобятся следующие свойства:

- Высота заголовка задается с помощью [DataGreedView.ColumnHeadersHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheight(v=vs.110).aspx) в связке с [DataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheightsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx)(тут нужно проследить, чтобы не был включён режим AutoSize).
- Высоту строк можно задавать как индивидуально для каждой, например по размеру содержимого, так и для всех сразу. Для того чтобы задать базовый размер всех строк можно воспользоваться свойством [DataGridView.RowTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) и [DataGridViewRow.Height](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.height(v=vs.110).aspx) соответственно, например `dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 30;`. Шаблонная строка используется для установки начальных параметров всех остальных строк грида и не запрещает в дальнейшем менять их параметры.

Конечно, для того чтобы задать подходящие размеры придется немного посчитать.
Например высоту пустой области под последней строкой можно посчитать так:

```
var allAvailableHeght = dataGridView1.ClientSize.Height;
var rowAvailableHeght = allAvailableHeght - dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;
var emptiSpaceHeight = rowAvailableHeght % dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height;
```

Дальше остается решить задачу оптимизации и по известным числам вывести оптимальные размеры строк и заголовка.

Если для строк выставлена автоматическая высота по содержимому или просто строки не одинаковой высоты, придется считать суммарную высоту отображаемых строк, например так:

```
var displayedRowsHeight = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .Where(r => r.Displayed)
                            .Sum(r => r.Height);
```

Тут тоже есть нюанс, эта высота может быть больше высоты доступной для строк, т.к. если строка отображается хотя бы на один пиксель, свойство `Displayed` будет истинным. Тогда, если вычесть полученную высоту отображенных строк из доступной, которую мы считали выше, отрицательное значение будет означать, что нижняя строка отображается не полностью.

Ну и всегда нужно учитывать еще один момент, если ваш дизайн жестко регламентирует все параметры грида, включая высоту строк и заголовков, то избавиться от пустого пространства ниже последней строки не перекрашивая фон грида не получится.

Comment: Можно сделать первым способом, положив грид в какой-нибудь контейнер и задать ему dock? Я имею ввиду, что создам контейнер по размеру грида, положу сам грид в контейнер и выставлю ему dock заполнение. Это сработает?

Comment: Во втором способе не обязательно менять высоту все строк, можно подписаться на Scroll и проверять, если первая строка невидима, то уменьшать только ее высоту для компенсации разницы

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko не совсем понял к чему вы хотите применить Dock.

Comment: @АндрейNOP или увеличивать. да можно и так, там есть разные варианты.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я же только описал как посчитать высоту области. А конечное решение что и как менять за пользователем. Можно вообще обойтись увеличением высоты последней строки, не так красиво, зато быстро и с гарантией. Плюс при разной высоте строк высота пустой области может превысить средний размер строки, тогда в вашем варианте нужно будет уменьшать уже не одну а две или три.

Comment: @rdorn, согласен, кстати, мое решение не подойдет, т.к. невидимая в данный момент строка никак не повлияет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP еще одно решение "в лоб" - увеличить N строк на 1 пиксель, где N - высота пустой области. И на глаз почти не заметно, и в реализации просто.

Comment: @rdorn, не всё так просто, невидимые в данный момент строки никак не влияют на серую пустую область, т.к. выравнивание идет только во верхней видимой строке.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78998/discussion-between-rdorn-and--nop).